# Leaked GCP API Keys : Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys. Please see this Google Help Center article for details

Tags: android, google-maps, google-cloud-platform

I am getting this error from Play Store:

[image]

I tried to limit the access of API key within that file but still getting this error. How can I solve this?

Comment: Tried every possible solution on this site no use. I have had the same issue even after my multiple classes uses the same key from same source but it will only point out to one class that this is where the problem it should be giving me for the all of the classes.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that keys are not leaked via sites such as GitHub.

Notice the message wording "Your app contains exposed ...". That message did not say your app is exposing the keys.

You will need to delete the key and create a new key, update your app, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Delete current key and create new one. Also make sure you apply restrictions like HTTP referrers, IP Address restrictions etc. based on your use case. For more info, check this
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#api_key_restrictions

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the API key being included in your source code. Consider using Google's Secrets Gradle Plugin for Android to hide your API keys from source code. Documentation at https://github.com/google/secrets-gradle-plugin and demo by the author at https://youtu.be/X8lYNW_Or2o

Comment: I actually started getting the warning when I implemented the Secrets Gradle Plugin in my app, I didn't have it before.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9287711?hl=en) mentions 2 ways to remediate the issue. I believe only the second one applies to Android apps. What I did was restrict the API so it can only be used by my app and for the specific APIs I need (e.g., maps). The documentation says you can ignore the warning once you have done this, but it doesn't seem like you can get rid of it.